# Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading for loop

Tags: php

I have this problem, it says Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading on line 14

```
 for ($i=0; $i<$materialprice[]; $i++) { // line14
$materialprice[i] * $materialquantity[i] = $totalmaterialprice;
$totalmaterialprice[] = $totalmaterialprice;
}
$allmaterialprice = sum.$totalmaterialprice[];
```

May I know why [] is not acceptable?

Comment: do you want to use for loop for the count of the $materialprice array?

Comment: yup. how do i do that?

Comment: PHP has a perfect function called [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) for that. `count($materialprice)`

Answer (score 1):

There were lot of issues in the code. The correct code is as below. The total count will be in `$totalmaterialprice`

```
 $totalmaterialprice = 0;
 for ($i=0; $i<count($materialprice); $i++) { // line14
   $totalmaterialprice += $materialprice[$i] * $materialquantity[$i];
 }
 $allmaterialprice = $totalmaterialprice;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($materialprice); $i++) { // line14
    $totalmaterialprice[$i] =  $materialprice[i] * $materialquantity[i];
}
$allmaterialprice = array_sum($totalmaterialprice);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$totalmaterialprice = 0;
for ($i=0; $i<count($materialprice); $i++) { 
 $totalmaterialprice += $materialprice[$i] * $materialquantity[$i];
}
$allmaterialprice = $totalmaterialprice;
```

Hope this helps.